# How to configure Jackson Mapper to deserialize null value as an empty list

Tags: kotlin, jackson

Assuming I have the following Kotlin class:

```
data class Foo(val bar: String, val dates: List<LocalDate>)
```

How do I configure JacksonMapper to deserialize

```
  {
    "bar": "bar-value"
  }
```

to `Foo` instance with `dates` set to an emptyList()?

I was playing with:

- `enable(ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT)` (it has different purpose)
- secondary constructor with nullable `dates` (failed due to JVM signature clash)
- the default value for `dates` i.e. `val dates: List<LocalDate> = emptyList()`
- custom deserializer (wasn't invoked)

but without luck.

Answer (score 0):

adding

```
@field:JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.AS_EMPTY)
```

did the trick :)

However it would be great if I could set it globally.